# Git Bash Tab showing Path instead of Heading "Git Bash" on Windows Terminal

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

I just configured Git Bash in my windows terminal but the Heading tab shows path where the terminal is opened, i want it to show heading Git Bash only. Help would be Appreciated.

Here is the Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

First Tab is Git Bash whereas second is Powershell. I want the first tab to show heading **Git Bash** like the second one.

Here is the settings of my Windows Terminal

```
{
    "guid": "{abc00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}",
    "name": "Git Bash",
    "commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
    "hidden": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tabTitle` property in `settings.json`.

Add this line to your "Git Bash" profile.
`"tabTitle": "Git Bash",`

Comment: Not Working It's still the same

Comment: Older versions had an inconsistant implmentation of the `tabTile` feature. Try upgrading windows terminal.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.2.2234.0 or "Window title changes were not always reflected to the ... window. Now they are." It's still a pre-release but should come out soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

##### Using GUI

add `"suppressApplicationTitle": true`

##### OR

##### Using GUI

In "Settings" select your defined Profile, click on "Advanced"

Then change the slide button of "Suppress title changes" to "On"